# Curve tangent line with unknown gradient

Tags: curves, tangent-line, tangent-line-method

A curve with the equation $x^2-2x+3$ has point b, what is the absis of point b if the tangent line on b passes point (1,1)

I solved it by first finding the gradient of the curve which is 2x-2, then I continued making a line equation which passes trough point (1,1)

I got $(2x-2)(x-1)-1$ and because it is the tangent line, and i have to find the absis of point b, my logic is that it must be the intersection. so I did this

$$(2x-2)(x-1)-1=x^2-2x+3$$

which gave me an $x$ of $2$ and $0$.

Am I doing it right just plugging in the unknown gradient like that? if I'm wrong please correct me

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for the correction

Comment: Sorry about that, it was supposed to be part of the full question, but it was not needed in this part, I'll delete it. I also did a typo with one "a" at what is the absis of point a, it should have been point b

Comment: You surely mean $(2x-2)(x-1)\color{red}{+1}=x^2-2x+3$. Yes your reasoning is correct, but the way you write it should make a distinction between  $b(x_0,y_0)$ and the writing $y=(2x_0-2)(x-1)+1$ of the tangent line equation with general $(x,y)$.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. Another typo again, I'm really sorry it messed my whole answer

Comment: for next time : "abscissa" instead of "abscis"

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're asking for the two tangents to $y=x^2-2x+3$ passing through $(1,1)$.

You're approach can't be right because you get a polynomial of degree $2$ as equation of a tangent. A expression in the form $y=x^2+\dots$ cannot be a straight line...

I think the standard approach is the following.

A generic (non vertical) straight line passing through $(1,1)$ has the expression

$$y = m(x-1) + 1$$
for some real $m$. You are looking for those values of $m$ which make your line a tangent to $y=x^2-2x+3$.

A tangent of a parabola has the peculiarity that cross the parabola in a single point. The points $x_0$ in which your line cross the parabola must satisfy the two conditions
$$y_0 = m(x_0-1) + 1\,;\quad y_0 = x_0^2-2x_0+3\,.$$
This subtracting the two expressions you get that $x$ must solve
$$x_0^2-(2+m)x_0+2+m=0\,.$$
You want that the parabola and the line cross in a single point to have a tangent. So you want that the above equation has a single solution for $x_0$.

This means that the discriminant $\Delta$ of the second order equation must be $0$. You have

$$\Delta = (m-2)^2-4(m+2)=(m-2)(m+2),.$$

So your solution are $m=2$ and $m=-2$.

Indeed the two tangents to your parabola passing through $(1,1)$ are
$$y = 2(x-1) + 1 = 2x-1$$
and
$$y = -2(x-1)+1 = -2x+3\,.$$

Now the coordinate of $b$ can be find easily. You get that the two possibilities for $b$ are $(0,2)$ and $(2,2)$.

Comment: No, his approach isn't wrong : see my comment : the quadratic equation is meant as the abscissas equation that should have been written otherwise. This said [+1] for giving full explanations.

Comment: Thanks, those are the results I got too, I made too many mistakes on the question and my english is not good, so I just put in words I know. Thank you so much

Comment: thank you very much too @JeanMarie for the corrections and checking my answers!